# Strange syntax flaw in mingw

Tags: c++, mingw

AT LINE 23- cout<"" doesnt give any error instead removing this statement produces abnormal output. i have tried it in CodeBlocks using mingw32. when i remove this it gives-
Process returned 1984687287 (0x764DF487)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int ispalin(long num)
{
    long sum=0,n;
    short rem;
    n=num;

    while(n>0) {
        rem=n%10;
        sum=sum*10+rem;
        n/=10;
    }

    if(sum==num)return 1;
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int n=1;
    for(int i=999;i>=1;i--) {
        for(int j=999;j>=1;j--)
        {
            if((i*j)<=n)
            {
                cout<""; // LINE 23
                break;
            }
            if((i*i)<=n)
            {
                printf("%d",n);
                return 0;
            }
            if(ispalin(i*j))
            {
                n=i*j;
                cout<<n<<"\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why this actually works is because 'cout' gets converted implicitly to a void* and then compared to the empty string, resulting in a boolean which, in your code, is discarded.

Comment: Removing line 23 shouldn't change the behavior of your program. Are you sure it does?

Comment: If you want me to see a comment, you need to mention my name; click the "help" link for details. All-caps is considered equivalent to shouting. That statement `count<"";` *shouldn't* have any effect; please try your program again with it and without it, and clearly show us (by updating your question) what the output is in each case. Please copy-and-paste the exact output. Note that even `cout<<"";` should produce no output; why did you write that line in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't give an error because it's a legal, albeit fruitless, statement.  `ostream` objects are implicitly convertible to `void*`. So that expression results in a comparison between a `void*` and a `const char*`, which is legal.

As for your error when you remove the statement, I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: It's legal, but it has undefined behavior, since the two pointers don't point into the same (array) object. But it's not likely to cause any problems in practice; it will do the pointless comparison and discard the result. (Actually, with an optimizing compiler it's likely not to perform the comparison at all.)

Answer (score 2):

For the [insertion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)

```
if((i*j)<=n){
    cout<<"";
         ^ Need one more <  
   ...
     }
```

on some platform `cout` (implicitly `void*`)  object might get compared with empty string with `<` giving a boolean statement

And it throws error for me with Mingw 4.7.2

Comment: but the problem is that when as it is of no effect removing it must not effect my output but it does.. i have compiled it in CodeBlocks,which uses mingw3.2.